# FireFox for genymotion

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, android-emulator, genymotion

So I am trying to get a browser on my genymotion. at first I wated to get chrome mobile but I need to get that from the play store which I can not get cause it complains about me not having a data contract set up. So I though I could get firefox install via an [APK](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/mobile/releases/latest/android/multi/) like I did for the andoroid emulator that came with the sdk but it is not working. I know that it has somethign to do with genymotion being on x86 or something. Is there an alternative for me to get google chrome, or firefox on my geneymotion emualtor?

Comment: What is your exact problem? Because this is not very clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd rather use x86 version of Firefox for Android, such as https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/mobile/releases/latest-beta/android-x86/multi/

Comment: Omg how come i was not able to find this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, this guy has an extensive Google Apps installation process for virtual android devices...
after you install google apps, such as Google Play Store you are able to install anything you want ;)

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iCRNqCXGNK0

Answer (score 1):

Try this link:

https://download.mozilla.org/?product=fennec-latest&os=android-x86&lang=multi

(You can change the `os` parameter to `android-api-9` if you want the ARM version.)